# Column names not displayed with st.dataframe after PostgreSQL `SELECT *` into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, streamlit

Python 3.8.10
streamlit==1.9.0
pandas==1.4.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3

Loading a Postgres table directly into a Pandas DataFrame with the following code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(run_query("SELECT * FROM schema.tablename;"))
```

Displaying it with either `streamlit.dataframe(df) or streamlit.write(df)` loses the column names.

[image: No column names]

In order to capture the column names, I use this kluge.

```
# Initialize connection.
@st.experimental_singleton
def init_connection():
    return psycopg2.connect(**st.secrets["postgresservername"])      
conn = init_connection()

# Perform query.
@st.experimental_memo(ttl=600)
def run_query(query):
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(query)
        return cur.fetchall()
 
def load_table_as_dataframe(table):
    # This is super klugy. 
    data = run_query("SELECT * FROM schema.{};".format(str(table)))
    columns = run_query("SELECT *FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'schema' AND table_name = '{}';".format(str(table)))
    # Fish out the actual column names
    columns = [c[3] for c in columns]
    df = pd. DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
    return df
 
df = load_table_as_dataframe("tablename")
```

Which works...

[image: With column names]

***Is there a better way to collect the needed data (and columns names) into a Pandas DataFrame within Postgres and Streamlit?***

Comment: Why not use [**`pandas.read_sql`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using...

```
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM schema.{};".format(str(table)), conn)
```

...solved the issue. (Thx [@parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait))